# Bootstrap 5 navbar is not render with space-between

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, navbar, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap, inside of a **navbar** there are a **class: container-fluid**, this container is a **flexbox** and it has a **justify-content: space-between** property

Wht **class: container-fluid** elements does not apply "space-between" property and they are located like flex-start?

[image: bootstrap navbar render]

The correct render must be

[image: navbar render how it must be]

**What is the explication and how to correct that.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is change inside ul tag  CLASS **mr-auto** TO **ml-auto**

```
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```